# Laravel - traer datos del usuario logueado desde otra tabla relacionada

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6

Lo que sucede es que tengo una tabla llamada usuarios y otra procesos. En procesos tengo un campo con el id de un usuario entonces me gustaría saber como traer la información de ese proceso

```
tabla usuario: id, nombre, contraseña, rol

tabla proceso: id, id_usuario, descripción, entre otros campo
```

Entonces al iniciar sesión con ese usuario me gustaría ver la información del proceso asignado al id del logueado

**Modelo de proceso:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;


class Process extends Model
{
    use HasRoles;

    protected $fillable = [
        'process_type', 'service_id', 'claimant', 'defendant', 'dependant_id', 'city', 'office', 'filed', 'status',
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function service() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Service');
    }

    public function history() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\History');
    }
}
```

**Modelo de usuario:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

   /**
    * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function process() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Process');
    }
}
```

pues hice el de imprimir usuario con

```
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
```

Comment: ¿qué has intentado?, ¿tienes los modelos creados?, ¿declaraste las respectivas relaciones?; la respuesta puede y dependerá de esto

Comment: he imprimido los datos de la misma tabla de usuarios, falta la de procesos, tengo modelos y relaciones

Comment: No amigo, por favor edita y agrega todo el código relevante como texto y no como imagen

Comment: me aparecen errores

Comment: estoy intentando agregar el codigo porque me aparecen errores

Comment: Ya tengo una respuesta para tu duda, pero pregunto ¿tienes algún intento hecho que pudieras mostrar?

Comment: pues hice el de imprimir usuario con {{ Auth::user()->name }} pero no que cosa quieres que te muestre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que estás usando Eloquent para definir las relaciones entre los modelos, podemos obtener el resultado deseado relativamente fácil con esta consulta:

```
.................
.................
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class TuController extends Controller
{
    $data = Process::with('user')->findOrFail(Auth::id());  
    .................................
}
```

**Explicación**

- En una propiedad `$data` almacenamos la consulta
- Usamos el modelo `Process` y apoyándonos de *eager loading* cargamos todos sus registros con el método `user`
- Para filtrar y encontrar uno en específico usamos el método `findOrFail`
- Con ayuda del *helper* `auth` obtenemos de `user` la propiedad `id`

La anterior consulta una vez que te encuentras logueqado en el sistema debería permitirte consultar solo el proceso que le pertenece al usuario que inicio sesión comprobándolo por medio de su `id`.
* Importa el *facade* de `Auth` al inicio de tu controller

Ahora en tu vista harías lo siguiente:

```
{{ $data->columna1 }}
{{ $data->columna2 }}
{{ $data->columnaN }}
```

- Al utilizar el método `findOrFail` estas en teoría obteniendo solo un objeto
- Donde yo coloco columna1....ColumnaN me refiero a los nombres de las columnas de tu tabla que serían los que estarían los que estás trayendo con tu consulta por lo tanto esos valores son los que debes editar y cambiar tu

Comment: amigo otra pregunta. es que un usuario puede tener varios procesos, entonces como podria hacer para ponerlos a todos en una tabla? por que solo me aparece uno. hasta donde tengo entendido findOrFail solo obtiene 1

Comment: Entonces la relación que presentas no es la correcta ya que en tu código indicas `hasOne` cuando entonces debería ser `hasMany`, para que finalmente cambies en la vista hagas uso de un `foreach` para iterar los valores y obtener todos los procesos

Comment: La consulta en teoría no, solo los cambios de la relación y luego hacer un foreach para iterar todos los procesos asociados a ese usuario

Comment: ya puse el hasMany en el modelo y hice una tabla con el foreach pero me suelta un error asi al hacer el $data->columna en este caso $data->process_id  "Property [process_type] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance"

Comment: Si el conjunto de resultados no es una colección, es decir múltiples registros entonces te devolverá solo objeto que no debes iterar y por eso te sale ese error, me parece que como tal la duda original ya fue resuelta, te invitaría que con ese error mejor abras una nueva pregunta

Comment: ya la cree amigo, si puedes ayudarme estaría agradecido. Gracias https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/336991/trying-to-get-property-process-type-of-non-object