# Trying to get property 'process_type' of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6, laravel-4

tengo dos tablas: una llamada usuarios y otra procesos, un usuario puede tener varios procesos pero al hacer un foreach me tira el error "Trying to get property 'process_type' of non-object"

modelo de usuario

```
public function process() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Process');
}
```

controlador

```
$processes = Process::with('user')->findOrFail(Auth::id());  
        return view('clientes.proceso')->with('processes', $processes);
```

vista

```
<table class="table">
                            <thead>
                              <th>Tipo de proceso</th>
                              <th>Demandado</th>
                              <th>Dependiente</th>
                              <th>Municipio</th>
                              <th>Oficina</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              @foreach ($processes as $process)
                                <tr>
                                  <td>{{ $process->process_type }}</td>
                                  <td>{{ $process->defendant }}</td>
                                  <td>{{ $process->dependant_id }}</td>
                                  <td>{{ $process->city}}</td>
                                  <td>{{ $process->office}}</td>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes mal el entendido de que estas llamando a los procesos de un usuario, te pongo la corrección

```
$processes = Auth::user()->process;
return view('clientes.proceso', compact('processes'));
```

Corrección modelo
Laravel automatiza los modelos, pero si tienes tablas personalizadas, debes mandarle la llave foránea como parámetro del hasMany

```
public function process() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Process', 'id_usuario');
}
```

Comment: amigo gracias por responder, pero me aparece este error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'processes.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `processes` where `processes`.`user_id` = 1 and `processes`.`user_id` is not null)"

Comment: ah ya pude con el error es por que pide un campo llamado user_id pero en lugar de ese campo necesito que se llame claimant, hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta editada

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió sos un pro